# How to log out with the Firebase Auth Rest Api?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Users who have certain user IDs can perform add and delete operations.

How can I log in and disable idToken to log out after adding or deleting, log out? Tokens have a 1-hour duration. People who are learning idToken can make additions and deletions. That's why it should be disabled.

I get idToken by requesting [https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key=[API_KEY]](https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key=%5BAPI_KEY%5D).

With the Firebase Realtime Rest Api xxx.com/abc.json?auth= endpoint, you can have the authority to add and delete.

Answer (score 0):

The REST API itself is stateless, so the only available information that someone is logged in is in your application that calls the REST API.

When you sign out in one of the Firebase SDKs they simply remove the ID token from the local state. I recommend you do the same: remove the ID token from memory effectively signs the user out.

---

Firebase only passes the ID token over encrypted connections, so is not susceptible to man-in-the-middle attacks (like the one you describe) unless your network is already compromised.

There is no way to revoke the ID token itself once it's minted, but if you want to revoke access for a specific ID token or user, have a look at https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions

Comment: In the database rules, I defined the rule that only XXXX user id can add and delete users table (users.json). While user YYYY adds new data in the application, he logs in to XXXX and adds with idToken. (Defined in the application. YYYY user does not know XXXX session information.)

Can user YYYY get idToken of user XXXX from Rest api replies on network? How can I do this authorization?

Comment: Firebase only passes the ID token over encrypted connections, so is not susceptible to man-in-the-middle attacks (like the one you describe) unless your network is already compromised. There is no way to revoke the ID token itself once it's minted, but if you want to revoke access for a specific ID token or user, have a look at https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions